# How to change script order of ng build index.html

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have inlined all script and style sources in my Angular index.html, to generate a single html file. I do so by running `ng build --prod` and afterwards I use `grunt-html-smoosher` to resolve all script and style tags. The result is in fact one HTML file with styles and scripts inside. 
But if I open it in the browser, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)
```

***EDIT:***

In fact, this error can be solved by putting the 3rd script (polyfills-es5) to the end.

Does anyone know, how to change the script order of `ng build --prod` programatically or with a script after ng build is finished?

Thank you in advance!